# How to share DB schema when there are two backend servers?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

I am developing some server. This server consists of one front-end and two back-ends. So far, I have completed the development of one back-end, and I want to develop the other one. Both are express servers and db is using mongodb. At this time, I am developing using the mongoose module, and I want to share a collection (ie schema). But I have already created a model file on one server. If so, I am wondering if I need to generate the same model file on the server I am developing now. Because if I modify the model file later, I have to modify both.

If there is a good way, please let me know with an example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers for you one is direct and the other will to introduce the concept of microservice.

## Answer 1 - Shared module (NPM or GIT)

You can create an additional project that will be an NPM lib (It can be installed via NPM or git submodules).
This lib will expose a factory method that will accept the mongoose option and return the mongoose connection.

Using a single Shared module will make it easier to update each backend after updating the DB (A bit cumbersome if you have many backends).

---

## Answer 2 - The microservice approach

In the microservice approach, each service (backend) manages its **own** DB and only it. This means that each service needs to expose an internal API for other services to use.
So instead of sharing lib, each service has a well-defined internal API that other services can use.

I would recommend looking into NestJS (NodeJS microservice framework) to get a better feel of how to approach microservice

---

It goes without saying that I prefer **Answer 2** but it's more complex and you may need to learn more before giving it a go. But I highlight recommend it because microservice (If implemented right) will make your code more future proof.

Comment: Oh... Thanks for explaining this to me.